# Can declared variables within my struct be of different size

Tags: c, struct, size, pic

Why I'm asking this is because following happens:

Defined in header:

```
typedef struct PID
{
// PID parameters
uint16_t Kp; // pGain
uint16_t Ki; // iGain
uint16_t Kd; // dGain

// PID calculations OLD ONES WHERE STATICS
int24_t pTerm;
int32_t iTerm;
int32_t dTerm;
int32_t PID;

// Extra variabels
int16_t CurrentError;

// PID Time
uint16_t tick;

}_PIDObject;
```

In C source:

```
static int16_t PIDUpdate(int16_t target, int16_t feedback)
{
      _PIDObject PID2_t;

  PID2_t.Kp = pGain2; // Has the value of 2000

      PID2_t.CurrentError = target - feedback; // Has the value of 57

      PID2_t.pTerm = PID2_t.Kp * PID2_t.CurrentError; // Should count this to (57x2000) = 114000
```

What happens when I debug is that it don't. The largest value I can define (kind of) in pGain2 is 1140. 1140x57 gives 64980.

Somehow it feels like the program thinks `PID2_t.pTerm` is a `uint16_t`. But it's not; it's declared bigger in the struct.

Has `PID2_t.pTerm` somehow got the value `uint16_t` from the first declared variables in the struct or
is it something wrong with the calculations, I have a `uint16_t` times a `int16_t`? This won't happen if I declare them outside a struct.

Also, here is my int def (have never been a problem before:

```
#ifdef __18CXX
typedef signed char int8_t;                 // -128 -> 127               // Char & Signed Char
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;              // 0 -> 255                  // Unsigned Char
typedef signed short int int16_t;           // -32768 -> 32767           // Int
typedef unsigned short int uint16_t;        // 0 -> 65535                // Unsigned Int
typedef signed short long int int24_t;      // -8388608 -> 8388607       // Short Long
typedef unsigned short long int uint24_t;   // 0 -> 16777215             // Unsigned Short Long
typedef signed long int int32_t;            // -2147483648 -> 2147483647 // Long
typedef unsigned long int uint32_t;         // 0 -> 4294967295           // Unsigned Long
#else
#   include <stdint.h>
#endif
```

Comment: Looks like your int24_t is defined to be 16 bits. Let's see the typedef? :)

Comment: The more important question: How big is `int`? Could you check `INT_MAX`/`UINT_MAX` in `limits.h`?

Comment: I never included limits.h in my project!

Comment: Nevertheless, `int` has a certain width/precision on each platform ... which can be deduced `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
PID2_t.pTerm = ((int24_t) PID2_t.Kp) * ((int24_t)PID2_t.CurrentError);
```

Joachim's comment explains why this works.  The compiler isn't promoting the multiplicands to `int24_t` before multiplying, so there's an overflow.  If we manually promote using casts, there is no overflow.

Comment: Not the problem, see the discussion on my answer.

Comment: @Kevin: ... except if it is a 16-bit platform (or something more wierd).

Comment: @dmc: With that you wrote: It works. But it does'nt answer my question

Comment: Could it be a compiler error when Im declaring different sizes inside a struct?

Comment: I thought I'd explain since I apparently confused the conversation with my assumption that int was 32 bit. The proof was the type definitions, it's an 18Cxx PIC which has int16_t integers. What happens is that the two 16-bit values are promoted to int (signed int16 since one of them is) and multiplied, with the overflow thrown away. After that they're promoted to 24 bit due to the assignment (int24_t fascinatingly actually is 24 bits on this architecture) The line above solves the situation by promoting both factors to 24 bits before multiplication, thus not generating any overflow.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: To be precise, the integer promotion promotes `CurrentError` to `unsigned`/`uint16_t` (because `Kp` has that type and `unsigned` is preferred), so the multiplication is carried out in `uint16_t`.

Comment: Yes, @undur_gongor is right, I misread the specification. It is indeed unsigned that is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

My system doesn't have an `int24_t`, so as some comments have said, where is that coming from?

After Joachim's comment, I wrote up a short test:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        uint16_t a = 2000, b = 57;
        uint16_t c = a * b;
        printf("%x\n%x\n", a*b, c);
}
```

Output:

```
1bd50
bd50
```

So you're getting the first 2 bytes, consistent with an `int16_t`. So the problem does seem to be that your `int24_t` is not defined correctly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the values are guaranteed to be promoted to int before they're multiplied. Assuming a 32 bit architecture, the result should be correct without casts.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson If you can find that in the ISO standard, I'll change or remove my answer.

Comment: Only found a draft, clearest in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf page 14 Example 2; In executing the fragment
char c1, c2;
/* ... */
c1 = c1 + c2;
the ‘‘integer promotions’’ require that the abstract machine promote the value of each variable to int size
and then add the two ints and truncate the sum.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, I also wrote a short test program and updated my post accordingly.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: The assumption (32bit) seems to be wrong. PIDs are widely used in embedded control systems, where 16bit micros are still common. So, I guess dmc's answer is correct.

Answer (score -1):

As others have pointed out, your `int24_t` appears to be defined to be 16 bits. Beside the fact that it's too small, you should be careful with this type definition in general. stdint.h specifies  the `uint_Nt` types to be exactly N bits. So assuming your processor and compiler don't actually have a 24-bit data type, you're breaking with the standard convention. If you're going to end up defining it as a 32-bit type, it'd be more reasonable to name it `uint_least24_t`, which follows the pattern of integer types that are *at least* big enough to hold N bits. The distinction is important because somebody might expect `uint24_t` to rollover above 16777215.